# Could anyone suggest a good packet sniffer class for c++?

Tags: c++, packet-capture, winpcap, sniffing

Could anyone suggest a good packet sniffer class for c++?  Looking for a easy insertable class I can use in my c++ program, nothing complicated.

Comment: I am using the MC VC++ on a Windows platform.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You will never be able to intercept network traffic just by inserting a class into your project. Packet capture functionality requires kernel mode support, hence you will at the very least need to have your application require or install libpcap/WinPcap, as Will Dean pointed out.

Most modern Unix-like distributions include libpcap out of the box, in which case you could take a look at this very simple example: http://www.tcpdump.org/pcap.htm

If you're using Windows, you're more or less on your own, although [WinPcap](http://www.winpcap.org/) programming is extremely similar to libpcap programming (unsurprisingly, since it's a libpcap port to Win32.) The SDK can be found here: http://www.winpcap.org/devel.htm

At any rate, no matter the operating system, you *will* need root / Administrator access to actually perform a capture. Just using the library to replay or analyze precaptured data doesn't require any special privilege, of course.

Comment: Nitpick: WinPcap offers the option of starting as a service so that non-admins can capture packets.

Comment: I know. However, doing this is a such *monumentally* bad idea, security-wise, that I'd rather not publicize it more.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to say something about your platform, as this is a platform rather than a language thing.

But assuming you're on something common, look into pcap or winpcap.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Network Monitor has a packet capture and analysis API, see [the netmon blog](http://blogs.technet.com/netmon/archive/2008/10/29/intro-to-the-network-monitor-api.aspx) for some basic info.